# push в mobx зацикливается в геометрическое прогрессии

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook, react-router-dom, mobx

Получение данных растёт в геометрической прогрессии, получаю данные и хочу их записать в массив, но когда нажимаю на кнопку в первый раз добавляется 200 данных если второй раз нажать, то 800, хотя каждый раз приходят всего 200, то есть идёт зацикливание бесконечное и всё больше данных парсятся хотя так не должно работать

```
this.todos.push
```

import { makeAutoObservable, makeObservable } from "mobx"

```
class Todo {
    todos = [
        { userId: 1, id: 1, title: '2311111111111', completed: false },
        { userId: 1, id: 1, title: '21322222222', completed: false },
        { userId: 1, id: 1, title: '3211111111111', completed: false },
    ]

    fetchtodo() {
        console.log("вызов");

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

console.log("1");
this.todos.push(...data, ...this.todos);
            })

    }
}

export default new Todo
```

код вызова в другом компоненте

```
function test() {

    console.log("вызов fetchtodo");
    Todo.fetchtodo();
}


Todo.todos.map((todo) => {
    console.log(todo.title);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в

```
this.todos.push(...data, ...this.todos);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

вы добавляете в `todos` новые записи из `data` плюс всё, что до этого было в todos

[Справка по push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)